# Code was correctly but show Error on node js socket io?

Tags: node.js

Code was correctly but show Error on node js socket io ?

....................................................................................................................

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

var clients = 0;
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    clients++;
    io.sockets.emit('boardcast', {message: clients + ' clients connected!'});

//console.log(io.sockets)

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        clients--;
        io.sockets.emit('boardcast', {message: clients + ' clients connected!'});
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('start server on port :3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io();
socket.on('boardcast', function(data){
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    document.write(data.message);
});
</script>

<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

.

ssh

```
node app.js
```

return value

```
start server on port :3000
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:6:6
```

Comment: express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:6:6

read this you have solution, it is `sendFile` not `sendfile`

Comment: When i change to `res.sendFile('index.html');`

--------

It's show error

-----------

Comment: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:421:11)
    at /home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/app.js:6:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)`

Comment: `at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/web/threadsbay.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/admin/web/threadsbay.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/admin/web/threadsbay.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next`

Comment: `(/home/admin/web/threadsbay.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/admin/web/threadsbay.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)`

Comment: where is your index.html file located ?

Comment: I think...you need to change your file path res.sendFile("To located path");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the commands from your question into an answer.

Express are depracating `res.sendfile` in favour of `res.sendFile`.

`sendFile` needs the full path to the file.

Assuming that `index.html` is in the same folder as `app.js` you can use:

```
const path = require('path');

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
```

If you move files around in the future simple tweak `path.join`